# How to get "Universal dependencies, enhanced" in response from Stanford coreNLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am playing around with the Stanford coreNLP parser and I am having a small issue that I assume is just something stupid I'm missing due to my lack of experience. I am currently using the node.js stanford-corenlp wrapper module with the latest full Java version of Stanford CoreNLP.

My current results are returning somehting similar to the "Collapsed Dependencies with CC processed" data here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/example.xml

I am trying to figure out how I can get the dependencies titled "Universal dependencies, enhanced" as show here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

If anyone can shed some light on even just what direction I need to research more about, it would be extremely helpful. Currently Google has not been helping much with the specific "Enhanced" results and I am just trying to find out what I need to pass,call or include in my annotators to get the results shown at the link above. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra (enhanced) dependencies can be enabled in the depparse annotator by using its 'depparse.extradependencies' option.

According to http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml it is set to NONE by default, and can be set to SUBJ_ONLY or MAXIMAL.

Comment: Thanks thomasin! That did it! Greatly appreciate the response.

Comment: Just incase anyone else is using the stanford-coreNLP node.js module, I figured I will just update that Hitesh was incredible in making such a quick update to the module today and you can now pass in the values above by making use of the new 'extra' object that you pass in the config with the key 'depparse.extradependencies' and then whatever value you desire.  You can see the proper way of using this in his updated sentiments.js example.